# How to be able to use a blank shortcode parameter to display all metabox values, rather than none

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a Wordpress custom shortcode I have developed, the query is below:

```
 $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'teamtype' => '' ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'team',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'publish_status' => 'published',
            'meta_query'       => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'          => 'my_key',
            'value'        => $atts['teamtype'],
            'compare'      => '=',
        ),

        array(
            'key'          => 'meta-featured_checkbox',
            'value'        => 'yes',
            'compare'      => '=',
        )
    ),
    );
```

It queries a custom meta key called "my_key".
And therefore the shortcode uses the parameter as so: [shortcodename teamtype="type1"]

I would like to be able to leave the parameter blank to display all values of the my_key meta key, such as [shortcodename teamtype=""]

When I use the arguments as below, without using a meta query array, I can leave the parameter blank to reveal all:

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'team',
                    'posts_per_page' => '10',
                    'publish_status' => 'published',
        'meta_key'       => 'my_key',
        'meta_value'     => $atts['teamtype']
                 );
```

Does anyone know why the top one doesn't allow me to do that? And how to make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working..!

In the meta_query array, for the parameter set in the shortcode, I used:
"meta_key" instead of "key" and
"meta_value" instead of "value"

such as:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'team',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'publish_status' => 'published',
            'meta_query'       => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'meta_key'          => 'my_key',
            'meta_value'        => $atts['teamtype'],
            'compare'      => '=',
        ),

        array(
            'key'          => 'meta-featured_checkbox',
            'value'        => 'yes',
            'compare'      => '=',
        )
    ),
    );
```